# Product Rule proof confusion

Tags: proof-explanation, combinations

I've got a textbook with this proof of the combinatorics product rule

$$|S \times T| = |S| \cdot |T|$$

It says let $S = \{s_1,\ldots,s_m\}$ and $T = \{t_1,\ldots,t_n\}$. We *induct* on $n = |T|$. If $T = 0$, then $S \times T = 0$ so that $|S \times T| = 0$ as desired. If $|T| \ge 1$, then let $T' = T - \{t_n\}$. We can write $S \times T = (S \times T')\; \stackrel{+}{\cup} (S \times \{t_n\})$. Also $S \times \{t_n\} = \{(s_1,t_n),\ldots,(s_m,t_n)\}$, which has $|S| = m$ elements since the second component is constant. Now, by the Sum Rule $|S \stackrel{+}{\cup} T| = |S| +  |T|$ and induction

$$|S \times T| = |S \times T'| + |S \times \{t_n\}| = m(n-1) + m = mn$$

which finishes the proof.

What I'm having trouble with is the idea of "induction on $n = |T|$". In what sense is this proof using induction? I really don't get strategy of why $T' = T - \{t_n\}$ is used. This is a page-one proof, so I guess the cross product is assumed, but I really don't understand how $|S \times T'|$ is $m(n-1)$ -- nor how this is induction.

Comment: One thing to note is the text is doing the induction step by assuming that $P(n-1)$ is true and proving $P(n)$ follows.  This may be somewhat less common than doing the induction step by assuming that $P(n)$ is true and proving $P(n+1)$ follows.  ... But these are both logically equivalent and equally valid.... Editorial. I think some mathematicians when using a base case of $0$ prefer to do a $P(n-1)\to P(n)$ proof rather than $P(n)\to P(n+1)$ proof as one is unlikely to make invalid assumptions about natural numbers that don't apply to $0$. (Ex. "All horses are the same color" proof)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine it were written as this:

Base Case: $n = |T| = 0$ then $S\times T = S\times 0=0$ so $|S\times T|=0 = |S|\cdot 0=m\cdot 0$.

Induction Step: Suppose that we know that if $|T| = n-1$ then $|S\times T| = |S||T| = |S|\cdot (n-1)=mn$.

Now the induction step is that we must prove if $|T| = n$ then $|S\times T| = |S|\times |T| = |S|\times n=mn$.

> *Perhaps this is part of what is confusing you.  As a matter of aesthetics I think it is more common and I prefer for the induction step to be stated as "we must prove $P(n)\implies P(n+1)$" whereas here they are saying "we must prove $P(n-1)\implies P(n)$".  Logically and practically these are both exactly the same thing.*

Pf:  Let $T= \{t_1,....,t_n\}$ and let $T' = T-\{t_n\} = \{t_1,.....,t_{n-1}\}$ and so $|T'|= n-1$ and by our assumption we know that $|S\times T'| = |S|\cdot (n-1)=m(n-1)$

And then.... we do what the text says....

The text proves $|S\times T| = |S\times T'| + |S\times \{t_n\}| = m(n-1) + m= mn$.

And we are done.

.... by induction.

Comment: You mean "...we know that $|S \times T'| = |S| \cdot (n - 1) \ldots$"?

Comment: Yeah, typo. ....

Answer (score 1):

Be careful: the $\times$ is not a cross product but a product of sets, i.e. the set containing all ordered pairs
$$S\times T=\{(s,t)\mid s\in S \land t\in T\}.$$

Now the induction is done on the cardinality of $T$: the base case is $|T|=0$ i.e. the empty set and then the induction step is done by including an extra element to the set $T$.

Let me know if you need a more detailed answer.

Comment: I think I understand now. The book proof left out the fact that $T' = T - \{t_n\}$ is really $\{t_1,\ldots,t_{n-1}\}$.

Answer (score 1):

This is the general scheme of an induction proof (clarification needs modus ponens).

Show the base case $P(0)$.
Assume that $P(n)$ holds for some $n\geq 0$. Then show $P(n+1)$.

As a consequence, $P(n)$ holds for all $n\geq 0$.

Here $P(n)$ is a predicate in the free variable $n$ such as the set $[m]\times [n]$ has cardinality $mn$, where $m,n\geq 0$.